# Retrieve from table different types and map it using myBatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I have a table:  `Person(int (primary key), varchar, varchar, varchar)` and `Skill(int (references to person id), varchar, integer)`.

The `Person` table contains column `kind` - it is varchar which indicates type of person. Person of different types has different skills - so `Skill` table.  No, in my Java classes I have abstract model of `Person` and concrete kinds, lets call them `A,B,C`.

Now, during retrieving data by mybatis I need create actual instances of class and return `List <Pokemon>`.  I have no idea how to reach this effect. Can you help me, please ?  Keep in mind that `Person` will be joined with `Skill`, so different instances in list has different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read MyBatis ducuments, [MyBatis3 - Mapper XML Files](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html).
For this kind of O/R Mapper, you need to create mapper files, which indicate actual model classes. After that, you should write some configurations to join tables.

**DDL**

I guess your table settings are like following:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` INT(10) 
  , `first_name` VARCHAR(18) 
  , `last_name` VARCHAR(18)
  , `kind` VARCHAR(1)
  , `age` INT);

CREATE TABLE `skill` (
  `id` INT(10)
  , `person_id` INT(10)
  , `desc` VARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO `person`(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `kind`, `age`)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', 'E', 33)
, (2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 'A', 24)
, (3, 'Jonny', 'Smith', 'B', 55)
, (4, 'J', 'J', 'T', 45)
, (5, 'Alan', 'Turing', 'C', 4);

INSERT INTO `skill`(`id`, `person_id`, `desc`)
VALUES (1, 1, 'John Smith is Engineer')
, (2, 2, 'Jane Smith is Artist')
, (3, 3, 'Jonny Smith is Butcher')
, (4, 4, 'J.J is Teacher')
, (5, 5, 'Alan Turing is Computer');
```

After configured, you can join two tables with a key. That's your `Pokemon` list.

```
SELECT * FROM `person` p
LEFT JOIN `skill` s
ON s.person_id = p.id;
```

SQLFiddle link → [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c44/2/0)

I believe your `person_id` can determine the record uniquely.

**Model classes**

Person class

```
// @Data <-- lombok can generate getter/setter easily
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String kind; // <-- it might be better to use enum
    private Integer age;
    // with getter/setter or annotations
}
```

Skill class

```
// @Data
public class Skill {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer personId;
    private String desc;
    // with getter/setter or annotations
}
```

Joined PersonSkill class

```
@Data
public class PersonSkill {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String kind;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer skillId;
    private String desc;    
}
```

**Mapper files**

XML configuration to save resultset as model classes

**PersonSkillMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="jp.gr.java_conf.hangedman.mybatis_join_sample.mappers.PersonSkillMapper">
    <resultMap id="personSkillResultMap" type="PersonSkill">
        <result property="id"        column="id" />
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <result property="lastName"  column="last_name" />
        <result property="kind"      column="kind" />
        <result property="age"       column="age" />
        <result property="skillId"   column="skill_id" />
        <result property="desc"      column="desc" />
    </resultMap>
    <select id="selectList" resultMap="personSkillResultMap">
        SELECT
            p.*
            , s.id AS skill_id
            , s.desc AS desc 
        FROM `person` p

        LEFT JOIN `skill` s
        ON s.person_id = p.id
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**Run**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/mybatis-config.xml")) {
            SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(in);

            try (SqlSession session = factory.openSession()) {

                List<PersonSkill> pskills = session
                        .selectList("jp.gr.java_conf.hangedman.mybatis_join_sample.mappers.PersonSkillMapper.selectList");
                for (PersonSkill ps : pskills) {
                    System.out.println(ps.toString());
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS**
If you would like to create some variable attributes, you might want to use `Generics`. Please comment if you want to use that.